# The difference between truncate table at Server DB and truncate table at Local DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbforge

I have a db at my Server. This db has 2 tables : "processor" and "imp_account". And this is foreign key :

[image]

My problem is :

- When I'm using db at the Server ( another computer), I can truncate processor table without warning
- When I backup db and use at my local computer, I cannot truncate processor table (must delete the foreign key before truncate table). Here is the error :

[image]

So why does this problem occur ? Sorry my English is not good.

Comment: either you drop the FK or just specify ` ON DELETE CASCADE ` which will delete the reference rows from the other table

Comment: You have to truncate the other table first.

Comment: Do you have the same data in your server and local computer.??

Comment: Hey guys, may be you did not understand my question. I know I have to delete the child first. But why "at Server I can truncate but at local I cant" ?

Comment: @Jhanvi : I sure I have the same db. I usually back up and restore between Server and my local.

Comment: @ntlam yes your db is same, but there is a possibility that there is a difference in your data, on your server and local computer, as this error does not come on server, it means on server there is no record creating the constraint on your key, while on local computer, some data is creating that constraint.

Comment: @Jhanvi : I dont think that. I back up Server db. Restore at my local. Ok, **now Server DB and local db is exactly the same**. Then I truncate at the same time, but this problem appears.